# How to get all IP addresses on local network

Tags: java, netbeans

I'm creating project that scan for available IP addresses on local network using java , but when I execute my code , it only shows me my IP address 192.168.137.15 but I want to see all the IP addresses available on the network.

I tried all the available codes on the Internet and none of them seems to work.
PLEASE HELP.

HostDiscovery Class:

```
public Future<HostDiscoveryResult> multithreadedHostDicovery(final ExecutorService exService){
    return exService.submit(() -> {
        try
        {
            String hName = null;
            boolean result = InetAddress.getByName(address).isReachable(discoveryTimeout);
             if (result)
            {
                hName = InetAddress.getByName(address).getHostName();
            }

            return new HostDiscoveryResult(address, result, hName, null);
        } catch (SocketException ex)
        {
            return new HostDiscoveryResult(address, false, null, null);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Where does 'address' come from?

Comment: There is no way to actively get all the IPs of a network in Java using a readily available API. However this does not mean you cannot go ahead and write your own implementation. The easiest way to do so, would be to actively ping a range of IP addresses and check which are the ones that respond. Your example does not do that and also is missing a lot of implementation details.